# Pervasive SQL german Umlauts Problem

Tags: c#, database, pervasive

I'm using the Pervasive SQL - ADO.NET 3.5 DataProvider for retrieving data out of the PSQL DB and I've noticed that the german umlauts (äöüÄÖÜ etc.) are not represented correctly in the `PSQLDataReader`, but in the Pervasive Control Center (similar to the sql management studio) the umlauts are all correct.

Is there anything similar to the `TSQL "SET LANGUAGE"`-command? I havn't found something like that for Pervasive SQL.

Googling this issue wasn't successful at all, too. Although I did find some tips with a file called upper.alt or collate.cfg, but don't know how to use this files and I coudn`t find them in my installation. (I'm totally new to Pervasive...)

I hope that someone on here could help me with that.

Thanks in advance

--EDIT

I sovled it in code, like so:

```
var ort = reader["Ort"].ToString().Trim();
var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ort);
ort = Encoding.GetEncoding(850).GetString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your Database have an alternate Code Page set in the PCC?  If so, you'll probably need to specify an "Encoding=" on the ADO.NET connection string.

Comment: That`s the way I solved it, encoding works fine, but just wanted to know how do I achieve this with PSQL.

Comment: You can specify the Encoding parameter on the connection string.  For example:
PsqlConnection conn = new PsqlConnection("ServerDSN=DEMODATA;ServerName=localhost;Encoding=850";